# docker service permissions on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, docker, permissions, docker-compose, ubuntu-16.04

I have an `ubuntu 16.04` and I have installed `docker` and `docker-compose` on it; but I can't run them without `sudo`. For `docker`:

```
docker build -t zizi .
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

For `docker-compose`:

```
docker-compose build 
Building ui
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localunixsocket - is it running?

If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
```

What are the permissions which I have to set?

Comment: i faced similar issues few days ago.. i found this and carried the steps on it.. hope this helps https://askubuntu.com/questions/477551/how-can-i-use-docker-without-sudo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it regarding @rhea's comment. I've previously added my username to the docker group; the trick was to run `newgrp docker` in order to log in to `docker` group. [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477551/how-can-i-use-docker-without-sudo?answertab=votes#tab-top) gave me the hint.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the users you want to give access to the `docker` group.

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker userName
```

Close and open your shell emulator after ypu made this change in order to get this working

Comment: Please read [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45952687/docker-service-permissions-on-ubuntu-16-04?answertab=active#tab-top).

Answer (score 0):

First of always install docker from their website

```
curl -SsL https://get.docker.com | sh
```

Next this will give you a message at the end that if you don't want to access docker using sudo then execute the command

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $(whoami)
```

Comment: Please read [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45952687/docker-service-permissions-on-ubuntu-16-04?answertab=active#tab-top).